# Energy consumer with 802.15.4 NIC Omnet++

Tags: omnet++, inet

I am trying to use **Ieee802154NarrowbandNic** with energy consumer **StateBasedEpEnergyConsumer**, but I am getting this runtime error:

```
Module not found on path '' defined by par 'Network.Node[0].wlan[0].radio.energyConsumer.energySourceModule' -- in module (inet::physicallayer::StateBasedEpEnergyConsumer) Network.Node[0].wlan[0].radio.energyConsumer (id=82), during network initialization
```

I have defined energy storage type in .ini file for all Nodes as - **IdealEpEnergyStorage**.
Just changing to default Ieee80211Nic works as expected. Is there something missing in .ned or .ini files?

Answer (score 0):

in file  Ieee802154NarrowbandNic.ned you can add the following lines and rebuild the inet . it should remove the error 
string energySourceModule;
*.energySourceModule = default(absPath(energySourceModule));